# php jquery obtener valor de un div

Tags: php, jquery, variables

Necesito pasar a letras (mediante un script PHP) una cifra que se inserta en un div mediante un cálculo en Jquery.
Necesito poner este valor en una variable PHP. No logro hacerlo.
Alguna sugerencia?
Aquí el código:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
//Subtotal 
 importe_total = 0
 $("#remitosfacturados .totalservicio").each(
  function(index, value) {
   importe_total = importe_total + eval($(this).val());
  }
 );
 var importe_totalEntero = importe_total; 
 var importe_total2Dec = importe_totalEntero.toFixed(2); 
 
 $("#remitosfacturados .subtotalfacturacion").html(importe_total2Dec);

//Calculo de IVA

var subtotal =  $("#remitosfacturados .subtotalfacturacion").html();
var IVA =  $("#remitosfacturados .porcentajeiva").val();

var resultadoIVA = (parseInt(subtotal) * (parseInt(IVA) / 100)).toFixed(2);

$("#remitosfacturados .iva_valor").html(resultadoIVA);


//TOTAL

var TotalFacturado = (parseInt(subtotal) + parseInt(resultadoIVA)).toFixed(2);

$("#remitosfacturados #totalfacturado").html(TotalFacturado);

});

</script>
```

```html
<div class="form-title">
<div class="form-two widget-shadow">
<?php


$TotalFacturadoParaLetras = AQUÍ DEBERÍA IR EL VALOR DEL DIV #totalfacturado;
echo $TotalFacturadoParaLetras;
include ("valoresenletras.php");
 $totalenletras=(string)$TotalFacturadoParaLetras; 
 $V=new EnLetras(); 
$con_letra=strtoupper($V->ValorEnLetras($totalenletras,'pesos')); 
echo '<b>'.$con_letra.'</b>'; 

?>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Para mandar el valor a php, tendrias que hacerlo con ajax

Comment: gracias @alanfcm !

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que usar Ajax para enviar el valor al script de PHP y poner la respuesta donde sea que la quieres en tu página. Ejemplo:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
//Subtotal  
    importe_total = 0
    $("#remitosfacturados .totalservicio").each(
        function(index, value) {
            importe_total = importe_total + eval($(this).val());
        }
    );
    var importe_totalEntero = importe_total; 
    var importe_total2Dec = importe_totalEntero.toFixed(2); 

    //Escribir importe en num y letra usando la función obtenerNombreDeCifra()
    $("#remitosfacturados .subtotalfacturacion").html((importe_total2Dec)
    + ' - ' 
    + obtenerNombreDeCifra(importe_total2Dec)); 

...

});

//funcion para enviar la cifra a PHP
function obtenerNombreDeCifra(cifra){
 let regreso;
 $.post( "ElScriptCorrecto.php", { cifra: cifra }, function(a){
   regreso = a;
 } );
 return regreso;
}
</script>
```

Luego en tu script PHP usas la variable POST:

```
<?php

//obtenemos el valor de POST
$TotalFacturadoParaLetras = $_POST['cifra'];

echo $TotalFacturadoParaLetras;
include ("valoresenletras.php");
...
?>
```

Nota: Para enviar valores a PHP y recibir valores procesados de vuelta es recomendable usar JSON en lugar de HTML o texto plano.